# Java Client Server UDP getting wrong packages

Tags: java, sockets, udp, client

for a little university project I have to code a Server and Client UDP communitcation.

If the client sends data and the server only reads, everything is fine. As soon as I start sending data from server to client my little programm bugs.

```
public class Sensors {
private static List<Produkt> allSensors = new ArrayList<Produkt>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Preparing Our Data
    initSensors();
    //Server Config
    String serverIP = new String();
    BufferedReader eingabe = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("IP Eintragen:");
    serverIP = eingabe.readLine();
    System.out.println("");

    //Preparing Data to Send

    try{
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(1234);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[4];
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                       receiveData.length);

        for(;;){

            //Sending
            for (Produkt s : allSensors) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
                os.writeObject(s);
                byte[] sendData = outputStream.toByteArray();
                InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
                DatagramPacket sendPacket= new DatagramPacket(sendData,sendData.length,ia,1223);
                serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
                outputStream.close();
            }
            for (Produkt s : allSensors) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            //Empfangen
            try{
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData(), 0,
                             receivePacket.getLength() );
            System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);

            }catch(IOException e){

            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            reduceValue();
        }

    }catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
  }



}

static public void initSensors() {

    allSensors.add(new Produkt("Äpfel", 0, 100, ""));
    allSensors.add(new Produkt("Birnen", 0, 100, ""));
    allSensors.add(new Produkt("Kiwis", 0, 100, ""));
    allSensors.add(new Produkt("Bananen", 0, 100, ""));
    for (Produkt s : allSensors) {
        System.out.print(s.p_name + " : " + s.p_quant + "\n");
    }
}

static public void reduceValue() {
    for (Produkt s : allSensors) {
        if (s.p_quant > 0) {
            s.p_quant -= 20;
        }
    }

}

static public void fillValue() {
    for (Produkt s : allSensors) {
        s.p_quant = 100;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Fridge extends Thread {

private static int port;
private static String htmlInsert = "";
private static DataShare ds;

public Fridge(int port, DataShare ds) {
    this.port = port;
    this.ds = ds;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println("Start Fridge Server");

    try {
        handleRequest();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Fridge.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

static public void handleRequest() throws Exception {
    try{
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        byte[] recivingData = new byte[512];

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(recivingData, recivingData.length);


        for(;;)
        {
            if(!ds.produkte.isEmpty()){
                if(ds.produkte.get(0).p_quant == 0){
                    ds.reOrder = true;
                }else{
                    ds.reOrder = false;
                }
            }
            //Empfangen
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            //prepare Data for conversion into Produkt
            recivingData = receivePacket.getData();
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(recivingData);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            Produkt reveivedProdukt = (Produkt) is.readObject();
            //Decoding Produkt into DataShare
            //System.out.println(reveivedProdukt);
            decodeData(reveivedProdukt);
            writeHTML();

            //Senden
            String reorder = new String();
            if(ds.reOrder){
                reorder = "FILL";
            }else{
                reorder ="NOT";
            }
            System.out.println(reorder);
            byte[] sendingDate = reorder.getBytes("UTF-8");
            DatagramPacket sendingPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendingDate, sendingDate.length,
                    receivePacket.getAddress(),receivePacket.getPort());
            serverSocket.send(sendingPacket);

        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

static public void writeHTML() throws Exception {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("<!DOCTYPE html>\n",
            "<html>\n",
            "   <head>\n",
            "       <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n",
            "       <title>Test</title>\n",
            "   </head>\n",
            "   <body>\n",
            "\n",
            "       <h1 style=\"color:red;\">Das ist ein Test</h1>\n",
            "\n",
            "   </body>\n",
            "</html>"));
    htmlInsert += "<p>";
    for(Produkt p : ds.produkte){
        htmlInsert+= p.p_name +" Preis: " + p.p_price + " Shopname: "+
                     p.shop_name + " Quantity: " + p.p_quant + "</br>";
    }

    htmlInsert+=  "</p></br>";              
    lines.add(6, htmlInsert);

    /* WINDOWS Path file = Paths.get(".\\src\\HttpServer\\data.html");*/ 
    /* LINUX*/ Path file = Paths.get("/home/debian/GitRepo/VSSS17/Fridge/src/HttpServer/data.html");
    Files.write(file, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

}

static public void decodeData(Produkt data) {

    Produkt comp = ds.getProduktByName(data.p_name);
    if (!comp.p_name.equals("Fail")) {
        //System.out.println("Changed" + data.p_name + "for amount: " + data.p_quant);
        ds.setQuant(data.p_name, data.p_quant);
    } else {
        ds.addProdukt(data);
    }

    //System.out.println("---");
    if (ds.getLegnth() != 0) {
    //    ds.print();
    }
    //System.out.println("---");

}
```

}

So as soon my quantity from Sensordata is 0, I start sending the "FILL" String to my client. The client only gets the "NOT" package. This goes on for around 50 packages until the client receives the "FILL" package. After this, the server is sending a "NOT" Package since the quantity is back to 100. But the client is still receiving the "FILL" package for again around 50 packages. I had diffrent approches like opening 2 sockets, one for reading one for writing. But it is still the same Problem.

I really don't understand why it doesn't work. Couldn't find any soulution for it on the internet either. Maybe you guys can help me.

Comment: UDP doesn't have reliability features. If you want reliability you have to code it yourself. NB The word is 'packet' not 'package', in this context. 'Datagram' would be better still.

Comment: You need to `close()` (or at least `flush()`) your ObjectOutputStream *before* you call the `toByteArray()` method of the wrapped ByteArrayOutputStream. That's as far as I got in the code.

Comment: what would be the best way to achieve a relibility? Is there a way to only send packets after i received one? I am pretty new with UDP and packet sending.

Comment: You need an ACK-based or NACK-based protocol. Too broad. Use TCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my Problem. I was sending 4 Packats in a look to the Server. The server was sending 4 Packets back. For each loop my Client was reading a Packet, he was sending 4 new Packets and getting 4 new Packets. So the Stack of Packets just grew.

I seperated the Reading and Writing of my Client into 2 Threads. Now its working pefectly